# How to remove attribute disabled from select

Tags: javascript, html

How to correctly remove attribute "disabled" from select in html template?
I created button and some select with few options:

```
<select id="testSelect" disabled>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

and next I would like to add script to remover that disabled atribute. I was trying with:

```
$("input[name=edit]").on("click", function () {
        document.getElementById('testSelect').disabled = false;
    })
```

but it does not work. It works with text inputs and checkboxes but with select I have problem.

Comment: `.removeAttr("disabled")`

Comment: `Element.removeAttribute()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("input[name=edit]").on("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('testSelect').disabled = false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="edit" type="button" value="Presto, enable the select!">

<select id="testSelect" disabled>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Your code is working fine for me. I've added an `input[name=edit]` matching element. Clicking it does, indeed, make the `select` element enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the `.disabled` property to false

```js
const element = document.getElementById('testSelect')
element.disabled = false
```

```html
<select id="testSelect" disabled>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

I'd assume that your script has issues with some other aspect that makes it not work, not 100% sure what though.